# How to replace "./" in Java?

Tags: java

How do I replace "./" with ""? 
I tried:

```
String s = "./";
s.replaceAll("\\./","");
```

Why won't the above work for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are 'normalizing' paths, the easiest way (although not the fastest, if in large quantities):

`new File(string).getCanonicalPath();`

it not only removes `./` but also interprets `../` and such (and in Windows, changes '/' to '\')

If it's a link, use `URL`

Answer (score 7):

`String` instances are immutable in Java, so `s.replaceAll()` does not modify `s` but will return a new `String` with the changes requested:

```
String s = "./";
String s_modified = s.replaceAll("\\./", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

It works but you should do :

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\./","");
```